# Draw continous line from unordered points

Tags: c#, arrays, algorithm, sorting, gis

I have sets of lat/long coordinates that comprise of several polylines. Each set of coordinates is a continuous line. For example,

```
Set 1 = 29.61357,-95.64925 29.61204,-95.65259,-95.65886 29.60898,-95.66032 29.60838,-95.66032
Set 2 = 29.61991,-95.63519 29.61957,-95.63648 29.61918,-95.63766 29.61795,-95.64047 29.61644,-95.6436 29.61465,-95.64699 29.61357,-95.64925
```

I want to merge the sets together to form a continuous line but, as represented by the coordinates above, the coordinates are not necessarily in the same order to make a continuous line (they both have the same start coordinate so one line would have to be reversed).

The end point on one set should always equal the start point on another set.

What is the most efficient method of traversing through the points (or lines), determining which lines need to be reversed, and then reversing them appropriately?

Comment: Are all sets guaranteed to have the same start point, and is each set ordered itself?

Comment: I think you just need to merge points and then sort by latitude.

Comment: Does the numbers in the set really matter? Don't you only need the first and last one? Or did I miss something?

Comment: Are the sets itself ordered?  ... so they really form a polyline? Your sample input is useless as you share only latitudes which is not enough as this is 2D problem. So to solve this we need to know about the two polylines ... can they intersect or self intersect ... how many times (once or more ?)  ... are the sets polylines start/endpoint matching? if yes then simply check the 4 combinations which 2 points are equal and either join or reverse join accordingly where exactly is the problem?

Comment: Yes, each individual set is ordered but not necessarily in the same direction. I've added the longitudes to add some clarity.

Comment: May you draw a picture to help me understand the question? I see the second point in set 1 has 2 longtitude which confuses me. and what's reversed lines I only find 2 points have the same value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your two polylines are polylines (points are ordered) its just matter of finding what to reverse and where to append. As the join point is exactly the same in both polylines its easy:

1. **definitions**

   let call the polylines `p[n]` and `q[m]` where `n,m` are the number of points. and lets new polyline is called `r[N] N=m+n-1`
2. **joint point**

   simply detect which one of the 4 scenarios is true:

   ```
   p[  0]==q[  0] // a
   p[  0]==q[m-1] // b
   p[n-1]==q[m-1] // c
   p[n-1]==q[  0] // d
   ```
3. **merge scenario a**

   ```
   r[  i]=p[n-1-i]; i={0,1,2,...n-1} // reverse p[]
   r[n+i]=q[i+1];   i={0,1,2,...m-2} // copy q[]
   ```
4. **merge scenario b**

   ```
   r[  i]=q[i];   i={0,1,2,...m-1} // copy q[]
   r[m+i]=p[i+1]; i={0,1,2,...n-2} // copy p[]
   ```
5. **merge scenario c**

   ```
   r[  i]=p[i];     i={0,1,2,...n-1} // copy p[]
   r[n+i]=q[m-2-i]; i={0,1,2,...m-2} // reverse q[]
   ```
6. **merge scenario d**

   ```
   r[  i]=p[i];     i={0,1,2,...n-1} // copy p[]
   r[n+i]=q[i+1];   i={0,1,2,...m-2} // copy q[]
   ```

Beware that `p[i]` is whole point (so both long,lat) so if your array is 1D you need to change the indexes and ranges a bit accordingly. Hope I did not make some silly mistake with the indexes but you should see the point how to do this even if I did...

Of coarse if your points are floating point its safer to compare with some margin of error so instead of

```
p[i] == q[j]
```

you should do something like:

```
|p[i]-q[j]| <= threshold
```

where threshold is some small value like `1e-10` ...